# User unable to login with via a ProtectedRoute using authContext

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jwt, react-router-dom, react-context

I am exploring the authContext based login approach for the protected routes in my app. I have created the following configs to support it:

###### AuthContext.jsx

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useReducer } from "react";
import AuthReducer from "./AuthReducer";

const AuthStateContext = createContext();
const AuthDispatchContext = createContext();

export const useAuthState = () => useContext(AuthStateContext);
export const useAuthDispatch = () => useContext(AuthDispatchContext);

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(AuthReducer, {
    isAuthenticated: false,
    token: null,
  });

  return (
    <AuthStateContext.Provider value={state}>
      <AuthDispatchContext.Provider value={dispatch}>
        {children}
      </AuthDispatchContext.Provider>
    </AuthStateContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

###### AuthReducer.jsx

```
const initialState = {
  isAuthenticated: false,
  token: null,
};

const AuthReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "LOGIN":
      return {
        ...state,
        isAuthenticated: true,
        token: action.payload.token,
      };
    case "LOGOUT":
      return {
        ...state,
        isAuthenticated: false,
        token: null,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default AuthReducer;
```

###### ProtectedRoute.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import { Navigate, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
import { useAuthState } from "./AuthContext";

export default function ProtectedRoute() {
  const { isAuthenticated } = useAuthState();
  return isAuthenticated ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/" />;
}
```

###### index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import { AuthProvider } from "./context/AuthContext";
import App from "./App";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <AuthProvider>
      <App />
    </AuthProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
```

###### App.js

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import ProtectedRoute from "./context/ProtectedRoute";
import { AuthProvider } from "./context/AuthContext";
import HomePage from "./home/HomePage";
import ErrorPage from "./errorPage/ErrorPage";
import LoginComponent from "./auth/login/LoginComponent";
import LandingPage from "./landingPage/LandingPage";

const App = () => {

return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
          <Route path="/login" element={<LoginComponent />} />

          <Route element={<ProtectedRoute />}>
            <Route path="/dashboard" element={<LandingPage />} />
          </Route>

          <Route path="*" element={<ErrorPage />} />

        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </AuthProvider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

The login component that's used to collect the username and password and to perform the login operation is as below:

###### LoginComponent.jsx

```
import { useAuthDispatch } from "../../context/AuthContext";
import axios from "axios";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const LoginComponent = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const authDispatch = useAuthDispatch;
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);

  const handleLogin = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    // API variable structure
    const loginInputs = {
      email,
      password,
    };

    try {
      const config = {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        },
      };

      const { data } = await axios.post(
        http://x.x.x.x/api/login,
        loginInputs,
        config
      );

      if (data) {
        const token = data.token;
        authDispatch({ type: "LOGIN", payload: { token } });
        navigate("/dashboard");
      } else {
        setError("Invalid username or password");
      }

    } catch (error) {
      setError(true);
    }
  };

return (
   // Some form code to take the username and password

 );
};

export default LoginComponent;
```

I am getting the token properly but somehow the login is not working. Seems some issue with the AuthContext. The authDispatch is not able to pass the payload correctly.

Answer (score 0):

There was a typo in the `LoginComponent.jsx` file:

```
const authDispatch = useAuthDispatch;
```

After changing this to below, all started working well.

```
const authDispatch = useAuthDispatch();
```